# How did check for not nil pass

Tags: swift

I don't understand how this if statement executed as timer is nil

```
        if timer != nil
        {
            logInfo("Cancelling notification for op=\(op), count=\(self.retryWindow.count)")
            timer!.invalidate()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is use the power of magical optionals.. No `if let` or `guard`.. since your timer is already an optional, call the method on top of an optional, and everything should be taken care by compiler automatically.

```
timer?.invalidate()
timer = nil
```

What it will do is call the method `invalidate` if `timer` exists.

Comment: Why the downvote, I didn't understand.. Whoever down voted, you owe an explanation... Please..

Answer (score 1):

Multi-threading is a possible cause. In between your `if` statement and your call to `invalidate`, `timer` could have been set to `nil` on another thread.

Don't check against `nil`. Safely unwrap.

```
if let timer = timer {
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed to be thread safe? Unwrapping also might involve an `if` check somewhere, which means another thread still has chances to mess with the value.

Comment: @Cristik Excellent question. I have to admit I just assumed an `if let` was atomic (therefore thread safe) but I can't find any indication either way. I think that deserves a question of its own.